# Include Sticky Posts with Custom Query Posts

Tags: wordpress, customization

I'm working with Custom Query in WordPress, Basically, I'm showing 4 most recent posts of a category having ID 4
and my **query** is as follows:-

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'cat'         => '3',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

This is working fine, but here I have an additional requirement. I want to add sticky posts as well i.e Posts will be stick to the top no matters these posts are recent or old, and total posts_per_page should be always 4 including sticky and recent posts.

e.g If there is no sticky post then I'll show 4 most recent posts and no sticky post. But if there is 1 sticky post then there will be 1 sticky post and 3 most recent posts, a total of 4 posts.

What modification should I made in my Query so that pagination also works fine as well? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you need to just select sticky post option form your post.

[image]

Then automatically work your scenario.
Example:

1. if you have selected one sticky post and you have set post per page 4 then `wp_query` will fetch the sticky post first and then show the other 3 posts.
2. if you have not selected sticky post and you have set post per page 4 then `wp_query` will fetch the only 4 posts without a sticky post.

It is WordPress default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

$args = array(
  'post_type'           => 'post' ,
  'orderby'             => 'date' ,
  'order'               => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page'      => 4,
  'cat'                 => '3',
  'paged'               => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post__in'            => isset( $sticky[0] ) ? $sticky[0] : array(),
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
  
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
```